# How To: Upload text file and use with PHP script

Tags: php, file-upload

Is it possible to achieve the following:

1. Allow a user to upload a text file via HTML form (.txt)
2. Use the contents of that file in a PHP script to temporarily access the information
3. Delete any traces of the temporary file after the script has processed?

Think of it as uploading a word document via html form, have a php script as basic as:

```
<?php

$document = file_get_contents("uploaded_document.txt");

echo $document;

$document = "";

?>
```

Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What exactly is your question? Are you aware of the examples in PHP's manual's [Handling File Uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unlink($_FILES["txt_file"]["tmp_name"]);
```

Comment: documentation is also his friend: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php